# Showing "Could not load SSL library." in BCB6

Tags: ssl

I am using BCPPB6 to maintain some legacy projects. One of these needs to GET data from a https URL. I found that the TNMHTTP comnponent that I have used for standard http GET operations in the past does not support https. However the Indy TIdHTTP component apparantly does.

With some trial and error I have found that it needs an Intercept component (TIdConnectionInterceptOpenSSL) and needs InterceptEnabled set to true. I then found that I need to have an OpenSSL library available. Thus I downloaded the latest version from http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/, extracted the two dll files and placed these into my application folder. However I continue to get the error "Could not load SSL library.". I have also tried it with archived versions of the OpenSSL from 2001 (around the date of 
my CPPB) and experimented with having the dlls in the System32 folder, all with the same error.

Is there anyone that can tell me what I am still doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure... but i was having a similar problem (on :=IdHTTP.Get('https://...');) till i used the DLLs:
http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/indy_OpenSSL096m.zip

Hope it helps you.